# show .OBJ in the screen using ObjectFile.TRIANGULATE

Tags: java, java-3d

I want to display a loaded object File.OBJ and show the vertex coordinates in the screen. but my problem is that:

```
int flags = ObjectFile.TRIANGULATE | ObjectFile.STRIPIFY | ObjectFile.RESIZE;
```

If I revised it to

```
int flags = ObjectFile.TRIANGULATE | ObjectFile.STRIPIFY;
```

This might bring me a non-resize loading, but fail to show it on the screen.

I'm wondering whether I can load it like

```
int flags = ObjectFile.TRIANGULATE | ObjectFile.STRIPIFY;
```

but afterward, I may add "ObjectFile.RESIZE" back into the loaded Scene so that it should be able to display in the view directly?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using ObjectFile.RESIZE?

Comment: because i want to get the real coordinates ( not resized).